# How to fix the Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Files GUI manager , Nautilus , flickers on and off

Tags: ubuntu, c++, mono, c#

I recently installed  Ubuntu Linux 15.10 on a Lenovo desktop.After a mysterious crash last night while testing point and click of an Mono-.NET 4.5 C# executable which DLLImport's an C++ shared object, the Files GUI manager , /usr/bin/xdg-open , flickers on and off .
  I removed the package xdg-utils and then installed it again followed by a system reboot and the  Files GUI manager , /usr/bin/xdg-open , * still * flickers on and off.
 Please advise me how to fix this problem.
 Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I goofed up. I meant to say Nautilus. Do I have to reinstall Nautilus? What is the name of the driver for Nautius? Thank you.

Comment: I just tried sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get upgrade followed my reboot and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a specialist in Linux systems integration today and this how we solved the Ubuntu Unity file manager blinking problem.

Another way to install the latest Nvidia GPU drivers is to go to the nvidia site and download the driver, then follow the installation instructions there to get it installed. This usually works better than using synaptic for the installation, but it is more complicated. [The driver utility](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/95165/en-us) also usually works well.

You can install XFCE4 along side Unity with the package manager. Just select XFCE4 and mark it for installation, or xubuntu-desktop (this adds further typical XFCE tools so you get the Xubuntu Desktop).

To logon to XFCE4, you first need to log out (or reboot), and then on the login page you should somewhere be able to select which desktop you want to log on to.

Comment: @svick, Thank you for the nice edit. Have you tried installing the latest Nvidia GPU drivers?